# how to query mysql database without repeats from one of the fields

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my current code:

```
<?php 
    $tsql = "  ";
    $tmpsort   = " ORDER BY b.flag,b.jjloveb DESC,b.yhtime ";
    $rt=$db->query("SELECT a.nickname, a.sex, a.grade, a.photo_s, a.photo_f, a.photo_pass, b.id,b.userid, b.datingkind, b.title, b.price, b.yhtime, b.maidian, b.content, b.bmnum, b.click, b.flag, b.jjloveb, a.birthday, b.province, b.city, b.area, b.age1, b.datingkind, a.identityproof
    FROM ".__TBL_MAIN__." a,".__TBL_DATING__." b
    WHERE $tsql b.flag>0 AND b.userid=a.id AND a.flag=1
    $tmpsort
    LIMIT 6");
    $total = $db->num_rows($rt);
    for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++) {
    $rows = $db->fetch_array($rt);
            if(!$rows) break;
            $Uid = $rows[7];
            $Unickname = badstr($rows[0]);
            $Usex      = $rows[1];
```

What I want is to fetch the records from the same user id only once.

Thanks very much!

Comment: You'll want to use `DISTINCT` or `LIMIT 1` depending on your case.

Comment: Look into `distinct` or possibly `group by` in your query.

Comment: why do you need to select data from 2 tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rt=$db->query("SELECT   a.nickname,a.sex,a.grade,a.photo_s,a.photo_f,a.photo_pass,b.id,b.userid,b.datingkind,b.title,b.price,b.yhtime,b.maidian,b.content,b.bmnum,b.click,b.flag,b.jjloveb,a.birthday,b.province,b.city,b.area,b.age1,b.datingkind,a.identityproof FROM ".__TBL_MAIN__." a,".__TBL_DATING__." b WHERE $tsql b.flag>0 AND b.userid=a.id AND a.flag=1 group by b.userid $tmpsort LIMIT 6");
```

I achieved what I wanted by just inserting a group by. Yeah!

But what about if 2 occurrences per userid is wanted, what approach should be taken?